# Fast fill 3D array/matrix in R with known index and value

Tags: r, performance, mapply

may I ask a stupid question about fast assigning values to a big 3D matrix in R? I have x, y, z for location index and val for values to fill. The for loop takes so long, could you please help? Note that here I just simulated xyz and val

```
x <- replicate(1e4, sample(seq(1:100), size = 1))
y <- replicate(1e4, sample(seq(1:100), size = 1))
z <- replicate(1e4, sample(seq(1:200), size = 1))
val <- rnorm(1e4, 0, 1)

a <- array(numeric(),c(100, 100, 200))
for(ii in seq(from = 1, to = length(x), by = 1)){
    a[x[ii], y[ii], z[ii]] <- val[ii]
}
```

I tied the following `mapply` but it returns to me a vector

`mapply(function(i, j, k, v) a[i, j, k] <- v, x, y , z, val)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```r
a[cbind(x, y, z)] <- val
```

It's difficult to show that this works on such a large example, so let's demonstrate on a smaller scale with a 3 x 3 x 3 matrix:

```r
a <- array(numeric(), c(3, 3, 3))

x <- c(3, 2, 1)
y <- c(1, 1, 1)
z <- c(1, 2, 3)
val <- c(1, 2, 3)
```

So these variables imply that we want a one in the third row of the first column of our first slice, a two in the second row of the first column of our second slice, and a three in the first row of the first column of our third slice:

```
a[cbind(x, y, z)] <- val

a
#> , , 1
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]   NA   NA   NA
#> [2,]   NA   NA   NA
#> [3,]    1   NA   NA
#> 
#> , , 2
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]   NA   NA   NA
#> [2,]    2   NA   NA
#> [3,]   NA   NA   NA
#> 
#> , , 3
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    3   NA   NA
#> [2,]   NA   NA   NA
#> [3,]   NA   NA   NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: @user1299648 sorry, my mistake - now updated.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works, I was testing it and the ```cbind``` solution took a blink.